image validation size setting in codeigniter 4
How can I specify accurately the size of image to be uploaded in a ci4 application. I wanted to upload an image of 49.7kb but cannot because of size restriction.
How can I set the size to 5mb max? Currently I guess i set it to 5mb
My image rules are:
$profile_pix_validation_rule = [
                'userfile' => [
                    'label' => 'Image File',
                    'errors' => ['max_size' => "Image size can be 10mb max"],
                    'rules' => [
                        'uploaded[passport_image]',
                        'mime_in[passport_image,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png]',
                        'max_size[profile_pix,5120]',
                        'max_dims[profile_pix,1024,768]',
                    ],
                ],
    ];


Maybe this is because your field name is different.
$profile_pix_validation_rule = [
    'passport_image' => [ // The correct field name
        'label' => 'Image File',
        'rules' => [
            'uploaded[passport_image]', // The field name here should match the input name
            'mime_in[passport_image,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png]', // Allowed mime types
            'max_size[passport_image,5120]',
            'max_dims[passport_image,1024,768]',
        ],
        'errors' => [
            'max_size' => 'Image size can be 5 MB max',
            'uploaded' => 'Please upload an image file.',
            'mime_in' => 'Only JPG, JPEG, and PNG files are allowed.',
            'max_dims' => 'Image dimensions should not exceed 1024x768 pixels.',
        ]
    ],
];


Additionally, the form should created with enctype="multipart/form-data"
Example of form (basic html)
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="passport_image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

And In php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 5M
post_max_size = 8M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300


Everything i have done corresponds to what you said here, yet the issue continues. I even changed the upload_max_filesize to 8m and the same problem continues.

@NjokuOkechukwuValentine passport_image field name is correct?

yes it corresponds to the input name like:
<input type = 'text' name = 'passport_image' ... />.
This is what I meant

@NjokuOkechukwuValentine input type is file not text

I really appreciate your being there to assist me. Thanks
